# MongoDB Delete records with date field less than days from another field

Tags: c#, mongodb

I have a collection which stores application logs in documents:

```
{
"_id" : ObjectId("5d92d5d01518a620ccaf015c"),
"MessageType" : "ApplocationLog",
"FireAndForget" : true,
"CreatedTimestamp" : ISODate("2019-10-01T06:28:00.198+01:00"),
"OriginReference" : "OriginReference",
"OriginName" : "OriginName",
"LogMessage" : "The log message",
"RetentionDays" : 1,
"LogSeverity" : "Error",
"ApplicationUserContextId" : "User1",
"ApplicationUserContextName" : "User1Name",
"Exception" : null,
"ErrorRelatedObjects" : null
}
```

I need to run a query to delete all records from the collection where the Current System Date minus 'RetentionDays' is greater than the 'CreatedTimestamp' of the document, i.e. remove expired log documents.

I am using MongoDB C# driver in my application and trying to figure the best way to do this. I have considered adding an expiry date when inserting the document which in hindsight might make things easier? But I still need to deal with the existing records using a query.

I have not got very far but started trying to work out the criteria for finding all records that have expired:

```
db.ApplicationLog.find({
"CreatedTimestamp": {
    $gte: 
        new Date(new Date().setDate(new Date().getDate()-1))
}
```

})

If I could subtract the 'RetentionDays' instead of the hardcoded 1 in the above maybe I could then add this to the criteria of a delete query? I'm new to MongoDB so struggling a bit with this.

Comment: Combine [$add](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/add/) and [$expr](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/expr/) maybe?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Bad News is you cant really do that in one query.

You will have to first "calculate" the new field and then use the documents that matched and call a remove operator, this can be done fairly easily using an aggregation by [subtracting](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/subtract/) from the date and matching documents with a negative result.

However if i may suggest a solution i personally find better:
Use [TTL index's](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/index-ttl/) this way each document will expire when its time for it to do so instead of you having to maintain a cron'd deletion query.

Here is an [example](http://hassansin.github.io/working-with-mongodb-ttl-index#expire-documents-at-a-specific-clock-time-or-dynamic-ttl) for a "dynamic" TTL index that you can use as reference.

Comment: This seems like the most sensible approach in terms of simplicity and performance. Thank you.

Comment: TTL seems to be definitely the way to go.  thank you

Answer (score 0):

One solution is to aggregate on `ApplicationLog` and filter the documents which need to be retained. Finally, replace the existing data with the output of aggregation.

**For example:**

```
db.ApplicationLog.aggregate([
    {
        $match:{
            $expr:{
                $gt:[
                    "$CreatedTimestamp",
                    {
                        $toDate:{
                            $subtract:[
                                new Date(),
                                {
                                    $multiply:[
                                        "$RetentionDays",
                                        86400000
                                    ]
                                }
                            ]
                        }
                    }
                ]
            }
        }
    },
    {
        $out:"ApplicationLog"
    }
])
```